# '$' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file when running Django

Tags: django, cmd

I'm new to Django and I'm trying to run a project on cmd:
'''
$ python3 manage.py runserver
'''

However, it shows:
'''
'$' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'''

Comment: You shouldn't put the `$`. That generally is there to show that is a terminal command. Just run `python3 manage.py runserver `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Drop the `$` – in tutorials and such, it's a placeholder for the shell entry line (where it's e.g. `C:\>` on Windows).

Just run

```
python3 manage.py runserver
```